# Why does my app listen to a perfect 75hz sine wave, and graph an uneven sine wave? (Flutter )

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, audio-recording, noise

[image]I have created an application in Flutter that I am testing on an android device. The application allows the user to hit record and sample incoming audio at a sample rate of 44100. After the recording is complete, the screen updates the graph to display 3500 samples. I have utilized two packages from pub.dev for this. I used Noise_meter and Syncfusion_charts. Noise meter gave me microphone access and had a default sample rate of 44100. Syncfusion had preset graphing abilities I plugged my incoming data into.
The problem I am experiencing is when I play a 75hz tone that should be a smooth sine wave, I am getting an uneven one. Some peaks are higher than others. I will include a picture.

I am taking and graphing samples 0 to i < 3500; i++.

This is the code for literally graphing it.

```
      SfCartesianChart(
          primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
          // Chart title
          title: ChartTitle(text: 'A Title'),
          // Enable legend
          legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
          // Enable tooltip
          tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
          series: <ChartSeries<_SoundData, int>>[
            LineSeries<_SoundData, int>(
                dataSource: dataList,
                xValueMapper: (_SoundData sound, _) => sound.index,
                yValueMapper: (_SoundData sound, _) => sound.sample,
                name: 'Samples',
                // Enable data label
                dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: false))
          ]),
```

The output is responsive. I have tried multiple different tones and it changes as expected. I have tried talking and tapping sounds. The graph is displaying what is taken in the recording. But it seems to lack accuracy. What I want is a perfect sine wave. I want to know why it is coming out with uneven peaks. I have measured the period length as well. That also was not consistent. It didn't have huge variation, but substantial. I need accuracy for the next step of my project. This was a baby step.
What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the charts?

Comment: It would be important to understand where the input comes from. This will only work when the input comes from a file.
If it comes from the microphone or mic jack input the sound goes through a hardware coder that is managed by a firmware driver which will translate the input into values.
This firmware drivers are adjusted to create reasonable outputs or pleasing outputs, not real outputs. So you are subject to hardware and firmware limitations for this purpose.

Comment: Dai -Yes! I had a photo in the original post, but I guess it didn't get loaded. I'll see if I can add it now

Comment: Over0n - Thank you! This is good information to know. The 75hz tone was indeed not a file, but just listened to via the androids microphone. To you direct me to a place where I can learn the specifics on limitations of the hardware?

Comment: The screenshot (thanks for adding it) looks to me like the charting library is adding its own line-smoothing rather than displaying raw points with straight-lines between points. I'm not familiar with Dart or the charting library you're using, but I assume there's a config/option/arg/parameter/property for controlling line/curve smoothing.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.